# Create macro to count from a sheet and fill the count in a table

Tags: vba, count, macros, fill, countif

## Initial Information

I have sheet1 which has the data with multiple columnn, and I have named the data ranges as well.

[image]

My second sheet has kind of a dashboard where I need to put the count according to the values.

[image]

### I have already Tried

1. Countif  - > gave  #VALUE! error
2. Countifs - > gave  #VALUE! error
3. sumif    - > gave  #VALUE! error
4. sum(if(component="Abc",1,0)) - > **Worked**, but since its an array formula i have to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

The problem with the last formula is that each time the data changes in sheet1 i have to go to sheet2 and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER on each cell. 
I need help with a Macro That can do the job.

Comment: As an easier alternative e you can use PivotTable

Comment: thanks for replying, but since i have to fill this in the dashboard kind of table, sometimes i need to use  AND / OR to the conditions so pivot table is not that great,  option if nothing works i use that only.

Comment: For Excel 2010 and above PowerPivot has more advanced filtering including AND / OR

Comment: What should i search on internet to get those advanced features?

Comment: It is available as a free add-in from Microsoft in Excel 2010 and 2013, and is included natively in Excel 2016. The and / or operators are `&&` and `||`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Sno` is in A1 and `Count` in G4 then in H6 copied across to I8:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$G6,$C:$C,H$5)
```

or with appropriate sheet references added, for example:

```
=COUNTIFS(sheet1!$B:$B,$G6,sheet1!$C:$C,H$5)
```

this could be placed on a different sheet from the data, and both formulae should work.

If not then perhaps you have a version of Excel that does not feature COUNTIFS, or your list delimiter is not `,` or something else is amiss that is neither function nor formula.

Comment: Your method works, but now a new challenge has come up. Now i have to check two values instead of one. So i need to do an

Comment: Your method works, but now a new challenge has come up. Now i have to check two values instead of one. So i need to do an

=COUNTIFS($B:$B,"WIP",$C:$C,OR  ($C$3,$C$6)    )

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNTIFS` (`RANGE OF` Status in the record, current cell with Status, `RANGE OF COMPONENT` in the record, Current cell with Component)
e.g:

```
COUNTIFS(B22:B28,A33,C22:C28,B32)


Sno Status  Component   

1   WIP Abc 
2   WIP Abc 
3   WIP Mnp 
4   WC  Mnp 
5   WC  Mnp 
6   RU  Abc 
7   RU  Mnp 

Count       Abc                                 Mnp 
WIP     =COUNTIFS(B22:B28,A33,C22:C28,B32)    =COUNTIFS(B22:B28,A33,C22:C28,C32)    
WC      =COUNTIFS(B22:B28,A34,C22:C28,B32)    =COUNTIFS(B22:B28,A34,C22:C28,C32)    
RU      =COUNTIFS(B22:B28,A35,C22:C28,B32)    =COUNTIFS(B22:B28,A35,C22:C28,C32)
```

Try this method. COUNTIFs will work.

Comment: Thankyou for replying but i have tried this medhod, and it gave me #value! error.

Comment: have added another answer which refers different sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Sno Status  Component
1   WIP     Abc
2   WIP     Abc
3   WIP     Mnp
4   WC      Mnp
5   WC      Mnp
6   RU      Abc
7   RU      Mnp

## in one sheet starting from A1 cell

in the next sheet from A1 cell

Count         Abc                                 Mnp
WIP     =COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B2:B8,Sheet3!A2,Sheet2!C2:C8,Sheet3!B1)    =COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B2:B8,Sheet3!A2,Sheet2!C2:C8,Sheet3!C1)

WC      =COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B2:B8,Sheet3!A3,Sheet2!C2:C8,Sheet3!B1)    =COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B2:B8,Sheet3!A3,Sheet2!C2:C8,Sheet3!C1)

RU      =COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B2:B8,Sheet3!A4,Sheet2!C2:C8,Sheet3!B1)    =COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B2:B8,Sheet3!A4,Sheet2!C2:C8,Sheet3!C1)